# How to run python from a network machine to local host?

Tags: python

I've a python script in the network machine, I can open the network through 
   explorer and have access to the script. Through that script from network,I      want to create some folders/files and write/read some files in my localhost.         Is there a way to do this in python?

Comment: Please add more details like which OS is installed on network machine. If it is linux, you can use remote commands to run those scripts in ssh sessions.

Comment: Local machine OS is windows 7.since I'm opening the network machine via file explorer from local machine, it is not necessary to run those scripts in ssh sessions.

Answer (score 0):

The good part is: you have read access on the script.

What you need is a python installation on your local machine and preferably a drive letter mapping to the script's folder. If not already mapped, this can be scripted with `net use <letter>: \\<remote host>\<shared folder>`.

Then it's as easy as `cd <letter>:\<path>\ ; python <script>.py`.

Then to the output of the script. Apparently it creates files. Can you supply the target folder on the script's command line? In that case just supply a local path.

Comment: Is it possible to run to the script without mapping the network drive.  The script is going to be in multiple network locations and it's hard for the user to map the network drive every time. I know mapping would be very easy, on the wide scale, I'd like to know the options without mapping.Thanks.

Comment: In order to navigate to the script's location, the network share must be mounted. From an MS-DOS prompt you can use `net use <drive letter>: \\<remote host>\<shared folder>` followed by `python <drive letter>:\<script>.py`

Comment: Thanks Freek for the swift response.Script is in \\<remote host>\<shared folder>\script.py and I want to create some folders/files in local machine(for eg C:\Users\XXX\Desktop). I can browse and run the script.py without mounting/mapping the drive, I'd like to know whether it is possible to create a directory in my local machine without mapping network drive.

Comment: Mapping the network drive is mandatory. I suggest a .bat file with two lines: `net use ...` and `python script.py`. As for the directory creation: that is not related to the location of the script. You're executing _on the local machine_ (despite the fact that the script is stored remotely) so the python script can use `os.makedirs("c:\\...\...\...")` as it pleases.